# Can´t reinstall grub after deleting it with boot repair

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I installed boot repair to repair the grub4dos screen I used a live usb stick.I deleted grub using boot repair but now I can´t reinstall it this is what it shows[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nps8M.png)

Edit:I retried it again and it worked.

and here is my paste from boot repair:

boot-repair-4ppa2056                                              [20231122_1540]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

=> libparted MBR boot code is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
=> Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc and looks at sector 1 of
the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

```
modules
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Boot files:        /etc/fstab
```

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD
```

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                   /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi
```

================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on sda5
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on sdb2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 2.L0(5.13) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0001,0002,0003
Boot0001* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0200)..GO..NO..........K.I.N.G.S.T.O.N. .S.A.4.0.0.S.3.7.1.2.0.G....................,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.5.2.0.B.6.6.7.9.7.4.0.C.4.8.3. . . . ........BO..NO..........S.A.M.S.U.N.G. .H.D.1.0.3.S.J....................,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.S.6.4.9.J.Z.0.5.1.9.6.4.1. . . . . . ........BO
Boot0002* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0300)..GO..NO..........T.S.S.T.c.o.r.p. .C.D.D.V.D.W. .S.H.-.2.2.4.D.B....................,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.9.R.U.4.Y.6.F.B.0.9.Q.2.1.5. . . . . . ........BO
Boot0003* USB KEY   BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0b00)..GO..NO..........K.I.O.X.I.A. .T.r.a.n.s.M.e.m.o.r.y. .1...0.0....................,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.............................F..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.0.2.2.C.F.F.6.B.D.8.E.C.4.6.0.C.1.1.C.2.5.E.4........BO
Boot0004* UEFI: KIOXIA TransMemory 1.00, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(12,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x95b33,0x800,0x39be000)..BO

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda5    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb2    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sdb2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sdb3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda5    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  no--grub.d, sda
sdb1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x26aec310
Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1             2048 1701863423 1701861376 811.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2       1701865470 1953523711  251658242   120G  5 Extended
sda5       1701865472 1901862911  199997440  95.4G 83 Linux
sda6       1901864960 1953523711   51658752  24.6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
Disk sdb: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x33530a2f
Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sdb1  *         2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sdb2         1026048 233370345 232344298 110.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sdb3       233371648 234436607   1064960   520M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
Disk sdc: 28.87 GiB, 31001149440 bytes, 60549120 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x00095b33
Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdc1  *     2048 60549119 60547072 28.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA SAMSUNG HD103SJ:;
1:1049kB:871GB:871GB:ntfs::;
2:871GB:1000GB:129GB:::;
5:871GB:974GB:102GB:ext4::;
6:974GB:1000GB:26.4GB:linux-swap(v1)::;
sdb:120GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA KINGSTON SA400S3:;
1:1049kB:525MB:524MB:ntfs::boot;
2:525MB:119GB:119GB:ntfs::;
3:119GB:120GB:545MB:ntfs::msftres;
sdc:31.0GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:KIOXIA TransMemory:;
1:1049kB:31.0GB:31.0GB:fat32::boot, lba;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL          PARTLABEL
sda
├─sda1 ntfs     4A322EA9322E9A49                     26aec310-01                          Second
├─sda2                                               26aec310-02
├─sda5 ext4     de4330cd-4348-4b5c-a078-59f704e0f716 26aec310-05
└─sda6 swap     61ff5817-0b15-4f1f-af24-e995f98c3edd 26aec310-06
sdb
├─sdb1 ntfs     EA3035FD3035D175                     33530a2f-01                          Sistem Ayrıldı
├─sdb2 ntfs     4CEC3835EC381C20                     33530a2f-02
└─sdb3 ntfs     00962B0E962B042E                     33530a2f-03
sdc
└─sdc1 vfat     8228-69A3                            00095b33-01                          UBUNTU 22_0

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

```
                       Avail Use% Mounted on
```

/dev/sda1                 175.5G  78% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda5                  79.2G  10% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sdb1                 470.1M   6% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdb3                  88.3M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb3
/dev/sdc1                  24.2G  16% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

========================== sda5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

## / was on /dev/sda5 during installation

UUID=de4330cd-4348-4b5c-a078-59f704e0f716 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

## swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation

UUID=61ff5817-0b15-4f1f-af24-e995f98c3edd none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

```
       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
```

816,291141510 = 876,485939200  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
816,291141510 = 876,485939200  boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic                  1
844,541213989 = 906,819223552  boot/initrd.img                                1
844,541213989 = 906,819223552  boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic               1
844,541213989 = 906,819223552  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

====================== sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

```
       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
        ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
```

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda2

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will purge (in order to fix packages) and reinstall the grub-pc of
sda5 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi will not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

LegacyWindows tespit edildi. Bilgisayarınız EFI modunda açılacak şekilde ayarlı. Bunu BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy moduna değiştirdikten sonra yeniden denemek isteyebilirsiniz.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?LegacyWindows detected. The boot of your PC is in EFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda (ATA SAMSUNG HD103SJ) disk!
Please set your BIOS in Legacy mode in order to start your Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, then type command [sudo update-grub] in order to add the Windows entry to your GRUB menu.

Comment: Does default repair to install grub to MBR of sda not work? You want Windows boot loader in MBR of sdb  & grub in MBR of sda. But you have newer UEFI system. Microsoft required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives in 2012. Best to totally reinstall Windows & Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode to gpt drives. But you need good backups as conversion from old MBR to gpt will totally erase the drive.